# Would you typically compile a java file before sharing it?

Tags: java, compilation

I'm new to Java and new to compiling. What are the pro's/con's of sharing java code that is compiled vs not compiled?

Comment: Depends on whom you're sharing with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you'd put the code in a source repository of some kind and that's how you share the code.

If you want the share the finished product, well, if it's a standalone app, build it into a full executable entity (using build systems, launch4j, etc – this gets a bit complicated to produce a fully stand-alone thing any end user with no knowledge of programming and nothing installed can just install and use) – and share that. If it's a webapp, host it someplace and share the URL.